# Getting "Unfortunately, app has stopped" while executing

Tags: android

I am learning Android dev in Android Studio.
I created an app which displays some text on fling and some other on click of a button.
But its showing "Unfortunately app has stopped"
Also, I have only one activity. So, its not possible that I forgot to show it in AndroidManifest.xml
here is my java code :

```
package com.example.mahe.pro2;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v4.view.GestureDetectorCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

private TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
private GestureDetectorCompat gd;
private Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.gd = new GestureDetectorCompat(this,this);

    bt.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    tv.setText("That was a Click!");
                }
            }
    );
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent motionEvent, MotionEvent motionEvent1, float v, float v1) {
    tv.setText("That was a Swipe, Baby");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    this.gd.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }


    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Here's my xml code :

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="YO!"
    android:id="@+id/t"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="62dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click"
    android:id="@+id/b"
    android:layout_below="@+id/t"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp" />
```

Comment: Show your logcat error

Answer (score 2):

Just move

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
Button bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
```

under `onCreate(...)` after   `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

Answer (score 1):

as @M D said
you must first create your view and setview to can get R.id.b

but if you want to declare them as a global variable , use

```
private TextView tv;
private Button bt
```

above the onCreate Method , then in onCreate method and under

setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

use

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t);
bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b);
```